# jQuery Colorbox not loading YouTube video properly

Tags: jquery, youtube, colorbox

I am trying to load a YouTube embedded link into my HTML using Colorbox. I can get the link to load, but it is actually jumping to the YouTube link playing full screen and not opening it in a color box pop up window. I have read through all of Jacklmoore's information, but I must be missing something. I am a novice with .js and just can't get this to work. Here is an example of my page: http://www.studio101westphotography.com/california-drone-photography.html

The small images below the the paragraph of text have the links that should produce a colorbox popup window. I have been trying to get two links to work and can't get them to load properly. I want it to pop up in a window that is approximately 640x360.